# MSOCAF Verification - Do not call overridable methods in constructors

Tags: c#, constructor, code-analysis

i have this error in MSOCAF :

> > 'ExcelChart.ExcelChart(ExcelDrawings, XmlNode, Uri, PackagePart, XmlDocument, XmlNode)' contains a call chain that results in a call to
> >     a virtual method defined by the class. Review the following call stack
> >     for unintended consequences:
>
> ExcelChart..ctor(ExcelDrawings, XmlNode, Uri, PackagePart,
>   XmlDocument, XmlNode) ExcelChart.InitChartLoad(ExcelDrawings,
>   XmlNode):Voi ExcelChart.GetChartType(String):eChartType

The constructor :

```
internal ExcelChart(ExcelDrawings drawings, XmlNode node, Uri uriChart, PackagePart part, XmlDocument chartXml, XmlNode chartNode) :
       base(drawings, node, "xdr:graphicFrame/xdr:nvGraphicFramePr/xdr:cNvPr/@name")
   {
       UriChart = uriChart;
       Part = part;
       ChartXml = chartXml;
       _chartNode = chartNode;
       InitChartLoad(drawings, chartNode);
       ChartType = GetChartType(chartNode.LocalName);
   }
```

And the line of the error :

```
XmlNode _chartNode = null;
    internal XmlNode ChartNode
    {
        get
        {
            return _chartNode;
        }
    }
```

The two methods :

```
private void InitChartLoad(ExcelDrawings drawings, XmlNode chartNode)
   {
       //SetChartType();
       bool isPivot = false;
       Init(drawings, chartNode);
       _chartSeries = new ExcelChartSeries(this, drawings.NameSpaceManager, _chartNode, isPivot /*ChartXml.SelectSingleNode(_chartPath, drawings.NameSpaceManager)*/);
       LoadAxis();
   }
```

and

```
internal virtual eChartType GetChartType(string name)
   {

       switch (name)
       {
           case "area3DChart":
               if(Grouping==eGrouping.Stacked)
               {
                   return eChartType.AreaStacked3D;
               }
               else if (Grouping == eGrouping.PercentStacked)
               {
                   return eChartType.AreaStacked1003D;
               }
               else
               {
                   return eChartType.Area3D;
               }
           case "areaChart":
               if (Grouping == eGrouping.Stacked)
               {
                   return eChartType.AreaStacked;
               }
               else if (Grouping == eGrouping.PercentStacked)
               {
                   return eChartType.AreaStacked100;
               }
               else
               {
                   return eChartType.Area;
               }
           case "bubbleChart":
               return eChartType.Bubble;
           case "doughnutChart":
               return eChartType.Doughnut;
           case "pie3DChart":
               return eChartType.Pie3D;
           case "pieChart":
               return eChartType.Pie;
           case "radarChart":
               return eChartType.Radar;
           case "scatterChart":
               return eChartType.XYScatter;
           case "surface3DChart":
           case "surfaceChart":
               return eChartType.Surface;
           case "stockChart":
               return eChartType.StockHLC;
           default:
               return 0;
       }           
   }
```

I found this code in CodePlex, and i try to resolve all errors MSOCAF returns

Comment: The code you show does not look like a method. The warning seems to be about `InitChartLoad()` and `GetChartType()`. What did you find when searching for the warning?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor `ExcelChart()` calls a virtual method, `GetChartType()`. Derived classes could override this method and use data which doesn't exist or isn't initialized at the point when the base class (ExcelChart) executes its constructor. The implementer of the base class cannot know or protect against later code which derives from his or her class, and the person deriving from it may not know that the base ctor calls a virtual method which he or she *really* wants to override.

That's why coding guidelines often forbid calling virtual methods in ctors.

Note that this implementation of virtual methods differs from C++ where those virtual methods are called which are in the vtable of the class whose ctor is executing; that is, in nested ctors each ctor may call a different version of the "same" virtual method. In C#, by contrast, always the "most derived" implementation in the inheritance chain is called. While this may be simpler and more predictable it is somewhat anti-paradigmatic to the idea of inheritance and leads to the danger of accessing data the base class doesn't 
know about.